# figure out the prime numbers between 0 and 1000?

Tags: c

I'm trying to make a programm that can calculate the prime numbers between 0 and 1000, the compiler says it has no warning and no erros too, but when i run the programm it gives me an execution error, i have no ideia what it is, does anybody could take a look at my code??

NOTE: i'm a beginner in programming.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(){

int i=0;

for (i=0;i<1000;i++){

if (i % 1 == 0 && i % i == 0){
printf("%d",i );
}
printf(" ");

}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: 1. What sort of execution error? 2. Your condition (`i % 1 == 0 && i % i == 0`) is true for every number, not just prime numbers.

Comment: You need to look up definition of a prime number.  That is not even close.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are performing a division by zero in

```
i % i == 0
```

for `i = 0`.

Moreover, even if you start you cycle from `i = 1`, the code will give you *every* integer between `1` and `999`, for the expression

```
i % 1 == 0 && i % i == 0
```

is true whenever `i != 0`.  Here is a fixed algorithm (not the most efficient, admittedly):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){

    int i;  /* no need to initialize to zero */
    int j;  /* we need a second counter */

    for (i=2;i<1000;i++){        /* start from 2 -- one is not prime            */
         for (j=2;j<i;j++){      /* check for nontrivial divisors               */
             if (i % j == 0) {
                 break;          /* nontrivial divisor found -> not a prime     */
             }
         }
         if (j == i) {           /* this means the cycle above run till end     */
             printf("%d ",i );   /* hence no nontrivial divisors, hence a prime */
         }
    }

    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why would you test against all numbers rather than just prime numbers found?  Let alone you don't need to test any numbers > 1/2 the value.

Comment: Because I tried to keep the algorithm as simple as possible, while declaring that it is rather poor, as long as efficiency is concerned.

Comment: Come on?  How complex is it to stop at 1/2 and double the efficiency?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with the expression `i % i`. In the first iteration of your loop, `i` is `0`, so you are dividing by zero.

Answer (score 0):

You should iterate from 1 to 1000, because dividing with 0 is not allowed and it gives floating point exception.
Also, your algorithm is not correct.
Use code from here:
http://www.programmingsimplified.com/c/source-code/c-program-for-prime-number

Answer (score 0):

What happens when i is 0? My guess is you want to start your loop at 1 (as well as fix your prime number check).

Answer (score 0):

Below python code may help you for following purposes:

1. To figure out the total number of primes in the range of 0 to given number (upper limit)
2. To know about each and every number whether that is prime or not
3. The Complete list of primes fall in the specified range

   primes=[]
   limit = int(input('What is the maximum limit?'))

   for n in range(2,limit+1):
     for x in range(2,n):
       if n%x == 0:
         print('{} -> Not prime'.format(n))
         break
     else:
         primes.append(n)
         print('{} -> Prime'.format(n))

   print(primes)
   print('Total {} primes found'.format(len(primes)))

If you don't want non-prime numbers to display then you can comment out `#print('{} -> Not prime'.format(n))` this line and if you don't even want to know all primes comment the consecutive print statement as well i.e. `#print('{} -> Prime'.format(n))`